# What is the difference between guidata(hObject, handles) and handles = guidata(hObject)?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Basically the same as above.

In my MATLAB GUI I have a pushbutton that retrieves data from textboxes and saves it in an array handle (more specifically multiple waypoints). I'm using this matrix in a later stage so I need the data stored in a handle.

In the callback function I call another function that does this (to keep my main file nice and tidy). Here, after saving all the data in the corresponding handle, I call `guidata(hObject, handles)` to save my changes.

However, outside of the function, in the callback, whenever I call `display(handle.data)`, it shows me the handle before I called the callback, although I refreshed it. Now calling another `guidata(hObject, handles)` directly in he callback doesn't change a thing, but if I call `handles = guidata(hObject)` it works.

My question: WHY? Is it just MATLAB?

CODE:

```
func_addWaypoint(hObject, handles)
display(handles.cart_coords)
handles = guidata(hObject);
display(handles.free_coords)
```

Note: the first `display()` gives me the old data, the second gives me new data.
Here is my function:

```
function func_addWaypoint(hObject,handles)

new_waypoint = nan(3,2);

coord_constraint = ones(3,2);


new_waypoint(1,1) = str2double(handles.edit_start_x1.String);
new_waypoint(2,1) = str2double(handles.edit_start_x2.String);
new_waypoint(3,1) = str2double(handles.edit_start_x3.String);

new_waypoint(1,2) = str2double(handles.edit_stop_x1.String);
new_waypoint(2,2) = str2double(handles.edit_stop_x2.String);
new_waypoint(3,2) = str2double(handles.edit_stop_x3.String);
v                   
for i = 1:numel(new_waypoint)
    if isnan(new_waypoint(i))
        new_waypoint(i) = rand() * 2 - 1;
        coord_constraint(i) = 0;
    end
end

handles.cart_coords = [handles.cart_coords, new_waypoint];
handles.free_coords = [handles.free_coords, coord_constraint];

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation for guidata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)

> guidata(object_handle,data) stores the variable data with the object
>   specified by object_handle.

vs

> data = guidata(object_handle) returns previously stored data, or an
>   empty matrix if nothing is stored.

Basically if you modify anything in the `handles` structure then make sure you call `guidata(hObject,handles)` before exiting the function.

Likewise if you are relying on custom information in handles that was modified somewhere else then call `handles = guidata(jObject)` at the top of your function.

Otherwise you will run into problems like you are seeing where you might have an old copy of the `handles` structure

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two copies of your variable `handles`: one exists in the [workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) *outside* of the function `func_addWaypoint`, and one exists *within* the workspace of `func_addWaypoint`. When you call the function, the data from the variable outside the function gets copied to the variable inside the function ([caveat](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152-can-matlab-pass-by-reference)).

You make modifications to the `handles` variable *within* the function and then attach that modified version to `hObject` using `guidata(hObject, handles);`. However, the original `handles` variable that exists in the workspace *outside* of the function still has the unmodified data. This variable is overwritten with the new values attached to `hObject` when you fetch them using `handles = guidata(hObject);`.